# Conditional launch of NavigationBar or TabBar + NavigationBar view

Tags: iphone

A typical Navigation-based app would have its MainWindow.xib contain a 'Window' and 'UINavigationController' -- this seems to work when a NavBar is your root view. If I want to show a NavBar view on launch based on one criteria and a TabBar otherwise, what's a good way to do this, utilizing Interface Builder for some of the layout of my views?

```
Workflow:
Default.png (Spash) -> NavBar with table or
Default.png (Spash) -> TabBar + NavBar with table
```

Are there any tutorials that would show some of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add both the `UINavigationController` and a `UITabBarController` to the app delegate.  In your `appDidFinishLaunching` just have the logic to decide which view to show and only add the correct view to the window.

In IB, you open your MainWindow.xib and you should have a Window and a Navigation Controller already.  Add a TabBarController there also, then link it up to the instance variable in the app delegate.

At any time, your app delegate can add either of these views ad subViews to the main Window.